# How to get Distance using RSSI value in android for BLE

Tags: android

How to get Distance using RSSI value in android for BLE.I am New in Android.
What Should I add in code for getting distance in meters.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device,int rssi){
    if (!leDevices.contains(device)){
        leDevices.add(device);
    }

    rssiMap.put(device, rssi);
}

public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
    return leDevices.get(position);
}
```

You can also check [this link](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag/blob/master/src/sample/ble/sensortag/adapters/BleDevicesAdapter.java) for more details, it may help you. You can also check the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html)